# What's the difference between running php script from cmd and webserver?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

Are the results the same between running a php script by web server and running the script by cmd with every environment variables ($_ENV, $_SERVER, $_GET and so on)?

In more specific, does following get the same result?

(1) the html I got by typing in "www.mysite.com/index.php" in browser

(2) the html I got by running cmd `php env.php` where env.php is like:

```
 <?php
   $_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]="CGI/1.1";
   $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]="127.0.0.1";
   $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]="";
   $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]="8080";
   $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]="nginx/1.4.6";
   $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]="HTTP/1.1";
   ... // all the other environment variables
   include "index.php";
```

If they are not the same, why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: they are not the same - but im not sure what the question is here

Comment: You would have to look at the *source* of the difference.. (ie. was some conditional false?)

Comment: @Dagon My question is: can I simulate the php script as running behind a web server (nginx/apache) by actually running it using bash? If I cannot, why?

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah, actually my question is if there is any differences.

Comment: Obviously there *is* a difference or the results would be the same. Then it merely comes down to *isolating* and *identifying* what the relevant (in this case) difference is.

Comment: still confused, nut you can "simulate" by using command line curl or wget